# Change persistance of J2SE session in ilog jrules

Tags: ilog, jrules, data-persistence

I have created a J2SE session in jrules to test my business rules. the rule engine is searching for the rule app in the /res_data directory by default. Is it possible to change the configuration of the rule engine to give a custom path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load a custom ra.xml in your classpath.
You can find the default ra.xml (default_ra.xml) in the META-INF folder of the lib jrules-res-execution-x.x.x.jar.
Then search for "DIRECTORY=res_data".

Comment: i have found the file you have specified but i did not understand how exactly i should change the path. for example if i would like my new res_data folder to be at "c:\jrules\res_data", where should i specify that?

Comment: replace DIRECTORY=res_data with DIRECTORY=c:\jrules\res_data and it should works